# What does the word "from" mean in the sentences below?

Tags: meaning

1.It's down the street "from" the museum.
2.It's around the corner "from" the theater.

Can we say that it is almost an opposite for "across from" ?

Comment: That’s a lookup.

Comment: This is the basic use of the preposition *from*, setting a starting point of measuring: سے

Comment: From is not related to near. "Down the street from" and "around the corner from" suggest nearness. But down from Everest and around the city are not near.

Answer (score 1):

"From" in this usage indicates a landmark (museum, theater) after which the particular place being sought is to be found.